# python m2crypt and load_key, but i have only a .cert files

Tags: python, openssl, pem, passbook

I have a problem.I'm testing some tips about Apple passbook with python. I'm using M2Crypto to obtain the signature.

The code is:

```
    def passwordCallback(*args, **kwds):
        return password

    smime = SMIME.SMIME()
    smime.load_key(key, certificate, callback=passwordCallback)
    pk7 = smime.sign(SMIME.BIO.MemoryBuffer(manifest), flags=SMIME.PKCS7_DETACHED | SMIME.PKCS7_BINARY)
    pem = SMIME.BIO.MemoryBuffer()
    pk7.write(pem)
    der = ''.join(l.strip() for l in pem.read().split('-----')[2].splitlines()).decode('base64')
```

The code is supposed to work well and generate the signature content, the problem is with the "key" and the "certificate".

This two variable are the name of certificate.pem and key.pem, but I have donwloaded only the pass.cert file from the Apple Developer portal.

How is possible to obtain this two files, with openssl or something similar?

SOLVED:

I have solved with this link

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Answer (score 0):

You need to either obtain a certificate from a third-party certification authority (CA) or create a self-signed certificate using something like the process described in [openSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt).  If you are just testing some code a self-signed cert will work, but a CA-issued cert provides other users some indication that you are who you the cert says you are.  You could create a self-signed cert claiming to be Tim_Cook@apple.com, but no reputable CA would issue you such a cert.